# How do I get another copy of elementaryos.iso?

Tags: software-installation

I paid for, and downloaded, a copy of the elementary image file, but during the process of creating a bootable USB, I discovered that I needed to be root user and that the .iso had to be in the root directory.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, which creates me as a non-privileged user. Inadvertantly, I deleted the elementary .iso using the Command Line Interface (CLI), thinking I could find it in the the Trash bin and move it to the root user account (foolish, I know); I cannot and the .iso file is now irretrievable.

As deserving as elementaryos is, I would rather not pay again (I didn't check the 'remember me' box); so, is there a way I can re-download a copy, having already paid for one?

Also, the installation of Unebootin requires the user (me) to be root in order to install and run the program. When I did run the program and tried to select the .iso file, I could not navigate from '/' (root) in order to make selection. It is proving difficult to install the operating system, particularly as, Unebootin has not updated its procedure for download and installation. Here, I would also appreciate some help.

Thank you.

Comment: Just download it again. In the section where it asks you to pay for it, put in "0.00" and download it. Also, unetbootin is buggy lately, use 'Balena Etcher' to burn the ISO to USB. You don't have to pay for the OS, just put $0.00 in the pay what you want section.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I would upvote you, but I have yet to fully navigate the site.

Comment: I can write it up as an answer. I probably should. Then you can 'accept' it. I'm not here for the points, I just like helping people when I have time. I also didn't know they had one for Elementary until recently.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this question a few times, not necessarily on SE. I don't think the site is intentionally deceptive, I just think people don't realize they can pay nothing and download the operating system for free.

Where it has custom amount, where you can pay where you want, enter 0.00 there. See the picture:

[image: pay what you want]

And then click to download it. You'll get this screen:

[image: start the download]

Just click to download. If you click on the 'magnet' then you'll download it with a torrent client and it will automatically verify the download for you.